# How to keep a new component after Search function is called?

Tags: reactjs, state, jsx, react-props

On a React project, I'm trying to link user's spotify playlist to an app page. Until this step, I've created quite a few components to enable user to search for songs, add the ones from the list to his spotify playlist (but user cannot see his previous playlists). 
I have added a dummy box to be utilized when I achieve to pull user's playlist info, the problem is when I type a song name and **click Search**, the box I created for this purpose disappears.

My code previous to adding latest SpotifyPlaylist box can be find in the following: https://github.com/basakulcay/Jammming

This is how it looks like before search:
[image]

I cannot find out where I need to make a change to make this happen. I think, it should be related to onSearch, but nothing I tried seemed to be working. ***Appreciate the help! :) ***

Below is the code from App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { SearchBar } from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import { SearchResults } from '../SearchResults/SearchResults.js';
import { Playlist } from '../Playlist/Playlist.js';
import Spotify from '../../util/Spotify.js';
import { SpotifyPlaylist } from '../spotifyPlaylist/SpotifyPlaylist';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [],
      playlistName: 'My Playlist',
      playlistTracks: [],
    };
    this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
    this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this);
    this.updatePlaylistName = this.updatePlaylistName.bind(this);
    this.savePlaylist = this.savePlaylist.bind(this);
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
  }

  addTrack(track) {
    let tracks = this.state.playlistTracks;
    if (tracks.find((savedTracks) => savedTracks.id === track.id)) {
      return;
    }
    tracks.push(track);
    this.setState({ playlistTracks: tracks });
  }

  removeTrack(track) {
    let tracks = this.state.playlistTracks;
    tracks = tracks.filter((currentTrack) => currentTrack.id !== track.id);
    this.setState({ playlistTracks: tracks });
  }

  updatePlaylistName(name) {
    this.setState({ playlistName: name });
  }

  savePlaylist() {
    const trackUris = this.state.playlistTracks.map((track) => track.uri);
    Spotify.savePlaylist(this.state.playlistName, trackUris).then(() => {
      this.setState({ playlistName: 'New Playlist', playlistTracks: [] });
    });
  }

  search(term) {
    Spotify.search(term).then((searchResults) => {
      this.setState({ searchResults: searchResults });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing
        </h1>
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar onSearch={this.search} />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults
              onAdd={this.addTrack}
              searchResults={this.state.searchResults}
            />
            <Playlist
              playlistName={this.state.playlistName}
              playlistTracks={this.state.playlistTracks}
              onRemove={this.removeTrack}
              onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName}
              onSave={this.savePlaylist}
            />
            <SpotifyPlaylist />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: please replace the image with a little of *relevant* code so we can help you debug

Comment: @RedBaron I wasn't really sure which file's code I am having trouble with, but I will post the App.js code as this is the one I am most doubtful about.

Comment: "the problem is when I type a song name and click Search, the box I created for this purpose disappears." if you start by showing the code related to that, we can go from there. and if we need to see more, we'll always ask

Comment: @RedBaron just added, I think it might be related search(term) method?

Comment: firstly I would say you call it like this: `<SearchBar onSearch={this.search} />`  but `search(term) {` you are passing in an arg. where is that coming from?

Comment: From Spotify.js :  search(term) {
    const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
    return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
    }).then((response) => {return response.json(); }).then((jsonResponse) => {
        if (!jsonResponse.tracks) {
          return [];
        }return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map((track) => ({
          id: track.id,
          name: track.name,
          artists: track.artists[0].name,
          album: track.album.name,
          uri: track.uri, }));});

Comment: yes but what I'm saying you have defined this `search(term) {` not the spotify part. but when you call the function `search` you don't pass anything to it??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215779/discussion-between-basak-ulcay-and-red-baron).